# Cast vs. Implicit conversion in C

Tags: c, casting, implicit-conversion

I was reading a book about secure coding in C and a point where i got lost is the difference between a *cast* and *implicit* conversion.
Please take a look at the following snippet:

```
unsigned char a = 1;
unsigned char b = 2;

int c = b - a ;  //presumably implicit conversion
printf("%u" , (int)a - b );  // presumably casting
```

I have found answers on Google but they're all concerning C# or even C++ but not plain C , so could anyone please explain what's the difference between doing `(int) a-b`  and assigning to another variable like this `int c = a - b`

What's really going on here?
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Implicit conversions are those done silently by the compiler. Cast are explicit conversions done by the programmer using the cast `(type)` operator. Regarding the implicit conversions in your example, this question uses almost an identical example: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

Answer (score 5):

Conversions can be either explicit or implicit. An explicit conversion is specified by a cast operator. A cast operator is a type name in parentheses preceding the expression to be converted. (You'll sometimes see the phrase "implicit cast". There's no such thing in C.)

For a given source and target type, an implicit conversion performs the same operation that a cast would perform. Some conversions, particularly most pointer conversions, are not performed implicitly and can only be done with a cast.

Implicit conversions are done in a lot of contexts in C. Some examples:

- In a simple assignment the right operand is implicitly converted to the type of the left operand. The same thing happens when passing an argument to a function, in an initializer, and when executing a `return` statement.
- When an operation like `+` is applied to operands of different arithmetic types, they are converted to a common type via a rather complicated set of rules.
- Integer types narrower than `int` are implicitly promoted to `int` or to `unsigned` int in many contexts.

This is not a complete list.

There are a number of implicit conversions in your example:

```
unsigned char a = 1;
unsigned char b = 2;
```

`1` and `2` are of type `int`. They are implicitly converted to `unsigned char` by the initializer.

```
int c = b - a ;  //presumably implicit conversion
```

`b` and `a` are both promoted to `int` [but see below] before the subtraction is performed -- not because the result will be used to initialize an `int` object, but because that's what the promotion rules specify. The result of the subtraction is of type `int`, so the initialization doesn't need to do another conversion.

```
printf("%u" , (int)a - b );  // presumably casting
```

The cast explicitly converts `a` (*not* `a-b`) from `unsigned char` to `int`. `b` is promoted to `int`. The expression `(int)a - b` is of type `int`, and is passed to `printf` -- which, because of the `"%u"` format is expecting an argument of type `unsigned int`. You can get away with mixing `int` and `unsigned int` in some contexts, but since the result of the subtraction is `-1`, which is outside the range of `unsigned int` the behavior is undefined. On my system it prints `4294967295`. With `%d`, it would print `-1`, which is the actual value of the expression. (You can cast to `unsigned int` if you want the `4294967295` output.)

[FOOTNOTE]

I said that values of type `unsigned char` are promoted to `int`. In fact integer expressions of a type narrower than `int` are converted to `int` *if* `int` can represent all the values of the narrow type, and to `unsigned int` otherwise. On some exotic systems, it's possible that `unsigned char` can represent larger values than signed `int`. On such a system, `unsigned char` promotes to `unsigned int`. You're unlikely to encounter such a system.

Comment: "The cast explicitly converts a (not a-b)" Well, implicitly it does. If we write `(long)a - b` then `b` will first get integer promoted to `int` as the first step of "the usual arithmetic conversions", but then it will get immediately promoted to `long` as the next step, since `a` is `long` which has greater conversion rank.

Comment: Regarding the footnote, a far more likely scenario is a 8/16 bit computer where an `unsigned short` (16 bits) cannot get promoted to `int` (16 bits), since `int` cannot represent all values. In that special case, the `unsigned short` gets converted to `unsigned int`. This scenario is encountered in any low-end microcontroller system using `unsigned short`.

Comment: @Lundin "*Well, implicitly it does*" -- I wouldn't put it that way. In `(long)a - b` the *cast* only converts `a` to `long`. The conversion of `b` to `long` happens because of the *usual arithmetic conversions* applied with the operands of an operator have different types. The cast is why the conversion happens, but only indirectly; the same conversion would happen with `1L - b`.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, promoting `unsigned char` to `unsigned int` is more common than promoting `unsigned char` to `unsigned int`. The latter requires `CHAR_BIT` to be at least 16, which is rare. But I was just addressing the code in the question (and even that was a bit of a digression).

Answer (score 3):

C converts values in many places. I have listed most, if not all, of them below. A cast is simply one of these places, distinguished by the fact that it is an explicitly requested conversion, whereas the others are automatic as part of the C language.

- For most binary operators, such as `+`, the two operands are converted to a common type using the *usual arithmetic conversions*.
- For most unary operands, the operand is converted using the *integer promotions*. This promotes any type narrower than `int` to `int` at least (with some technical details).
- Assignments convert the right operand to the type of the left operand (without qualifiers or the atomic property).
- An lvalue (a reference to an object, that is, a value stored in memory) is converted to the stored value, except when the lvalue is being used to modify the object or as the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` or the left operand of `.`
- An array is converted to a pointer to its first element except when it is the operand of `sizeof`, is the operand of unary `&`, or is a string literal used to initialize an array.
- Arguments in function calls are converted to the type of the parameter (if there is a function prototype and the argument does not correspond to a `...` part) or according to the *default argument promotions*.
- A cast converts its operand to the named type.
- In a `return` statement, the value is converted to the type returned by the function.
- In `case` labels, the constant in the label is converted to the promoted type of the expression in the `switch` statement.

In `int c = b - a;` in an ordinary C implementation, we have the following operations:

- The usual arithmetic conversions convert both `b` and `a` to `int`.
- The resulting values are subtracted.
- The result is converted to `int`. (Since it is already an `int`, there is no change).
- The result is used as the initial value of `c`.

In `printf("%u" , (int)a - b );`:

- `a` is converted to `int`.
- The usual arithmetic conversions convert `b` to `int`.
- The resulting values are subtracted.
- The default argument promotions leave the value as an `int`.
- `printf` is called.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed answer. . Could you elaborate please why does the first line yield -1 , while the second yiels a large positive number ?

Comment: @Ait-GacemNabil: The large positive number is not caused by casting but by the fact you used an incorrect `printf` conversion specifier. `%u` says “Expect to be passed an `unsigned int` and convert it to decimal.” But you passed an `int`. No conversion was performed; the argument is an `int`, and an `int` was passed. Formally, the program behavior is then undefined. Commonly, what happens is `printf` reinterprets the bits of an `int` as if they were an `unsigned int`. This is not a conversion. The bit pattern of −1 in 32-bit two’s complement is the same bit pattern as unsigned 4,294.967,295.

Comment: @Ait-GacemNabil change the `%u` in your printf() to `%d` and look at the difference

Comment: During the usual arithmetic conversions, both operands not just coverted to a common type. They are first promoted with the integer promotions and then after that is done, balanced after integer conversion rank. Otherwise `my_char + my_short` would have resulted in type `short` and not `int`.

Comment: @Lundin: The details of the usual arithmetic conversions are not particularly relevant, and I judge them not to be worth adding to the already long answer, as they require more discussion of real types prior to integer promotions and such. If your issue is that conversion to a “common type” means a type that is one of the types of the original operands, then it does not; it means both are converted to one type, which is also used for the result. This is the phrasing used in the C standard; C 2018 6.3.1.8 1 says “The purpose is to determine a *common real type* for the operands and the result.”

Answer (score 1):

> ...difference between doing **(int) a-b** and assigning to another
> variable like this **int c = a - b**

The assignment acts as a natural border; but your examples are not so clear, especially with `%u` and `(int)` cast.

To see the effect:

```
    char D = 13,
         d = 2;
    double x  = D/d;             // 6.000(double reaches not right side) 
    double y  = (double)D/d;     // 6.5  (Division involves a double/real)
    double z  = (double)(D/d);   // 6.000(too late, division done with integer type char)
    
    printf("%f %f %f\n", x, y, z);
```

With literal values, there is the elegant half-explicit conversion with `.0`.

```
double x = 13.0 / 2;         // like (double)13 / 2
```

One floating literal is enough to "infect" the division with fractions.

`double x = 13 / 2` gives 6.0 (see first example above) and would need a thick comment if this was intended.

**6.3 Conversions** is an own chapter between "Concepts" and "Lexical Elements". It gives the rules for *ordinary operators* and announces additional rules for the other operators in the main chapter.

Lundin's comment sums it up: compiler/C rules vs. `(cast)`

---

I mean his comment under OP. His comment here I also agree with. I wanted to address the two "*presumably*" in OP. And the direct A to title Q: Difference is...

Casts can and should be avoided, mostly; implicit conversions happen all the time, sometimes even the way you intend.

Comment: "One floating literal is enough to "infect" the division with fractions" That's a bit of an over-simplification. Consider `8/3/2.0`. Division operator associativity is left-to-right, so 8/3=2 is calculated first before division with a double, and so we get the result `1.0`. Whereas `8/3.0/2` gives the result `1.33`. This is because each `/` applies the usual arithmetic conversions on its 2 operands. In case of `8/3` nothing gets changed since the types are already `int`. Only in the next division the balancing to `double` happens.